# passing value through AJAX url attribute to server code

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, ejs

I am building an off-canvas overlay to show all the comments on a blog. I want to use ajax so that users can post and see the update of the comments section without reloading the page.

I have been using ejs syntax for my HTML files but when it goes to ajax, I don't know how to let the back end server recognize the data through the "erl" attribute in ajax.

my ajax code

```
$("#commentBtn").on("click", () => {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/home/<%=blog.title%>/comment",    <--- I want to send the title attribute of the blog to backend
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: (response) => {
                let commentElem = $("#showComments");

                response.comments.forEach(comment => {
                    commentElem.append('\
                        <h2>'+comment.id+'</h2>\
                        <h3>'+comment.content+'</h3>\
                    ');
                });
            }
        })
    })
```

related HTML code

```
<button type="button" id="commentBtn" uk-toggle="target: #offcanvas-usage">show comment</button>
```

my router

```
router.get("/home/:title/comment", async(req, res) => {
    await Blog.findOne({title: req.params.title}, (err, foundBlog) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else{
            *do the send comment things ....*
        }
    })
})
```

The problem now is the router cannot recognize `req.params.title`, I think it is the ajax issue that it didn't send the title of the blog to the router. so that the router cannot find the specific blog for me.

Is there any ajax syntax to let my router to use `req.params.title`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the  jQuery code  shown in an ejs file or js file?

Comment: the jquery code is in a js file

Comment: Then you need another way to pass the title to the js file. It will not be compiled by ejs. Inspect the actual request made in browser dev tools network and you will see it contains the literal string `"<%=blog.title%>"` not the variable value

Comment: Understood, thank you! I will try to find a way to pass the title of the blog to my js file. Or if you can point me some directions, I'll be appreciated too!

Comment: One way is with a simple script tag in ejs file and a javascript variable that you then use to concatenate in the url in js file. Not enough known about the rest of your app for more comprehensive approach

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ejs, but can you use template literals?

```
url: `/home/${blog.title}/comment`
```

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)